# what happened when function return

Tags: c++, function

I know when the caller function call the callee function, the caller function push the args and return address and then construct stack frame for callee function include push %ebp %ebx %edi %esi and push local variable. but what happened when the callee return?

Comment: Well, what's the inverse of the `push()` operation?

Comment: (Be warned that what you know is only one specific calling convention, many details can and will differ in other environments.)

Comment: e, it's the default calling convention in C/C++.

Comment: @stamaimer: On x86-32, and even then I'm not sure it's exactly the same on all OS'es. E.g. AFAIK Visual C++/x86-32 passes `this` in `ECX`, not the statk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually C++ has no standard application binary interface (ABI). C has, but a programmer might alter it by applying compiler specific calling conventions. An overview (machine x86) is at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Answer (score 0):

The callee saves the return value on the stack and returns.

Answer (score 0):

Callee function does the following task

```
-> push the address of previous stack frame
-> push the local variables
-> performs computation
-> restores previous stack frame
-> store the function result
-> jump to return address
```